# Log Moneyness vs Log Strike

Tags: option-pricing, volatility, black-scholes, implied-volatility

In [How to calibrate a volatility surface using SVI](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/19344/how-to-calibrate-a-volatility-surface-using-svi), is said: "(log-moneyness would be more accurate) ".

First, why do we talk about "moneyness", is it a reference of "being in the money"?

Second, why moneyness instead of strike ? Is it in order to remind that we are not talking about a defined strike priced but we are talking about a scaled striked i.e. moneyness?